# How to run a shell script without having to press enter/confirm s.th. inbetween

Tags: python, linux, shell

I'm currently writing a shell script which is interfacing with numerous python scripts. In one of these Python scripts I'm calling grass without starting it explicitly. When I run my shell script I have to hit enter at the point where I call grass (this is the code I got from the official working with [grass page](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly)):

```
startcmd = grass7bin + ' -c ' + file_in2 + ' -e ' + location_path 
print startcmd
p = subprocess.Popen(startcmd, shell=True, 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
 if p.returncode != 0:
    print >>sys.stderr, 'ERROR: %s' % err
    print >>sys.stderr, 'ERROR: Cannot generate location (%s)' % startcmd
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    print 'Created location %s' % location_path
gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)
```

My problem is that I want this process to run automatically without me having to press enter everytime in between!
I have already tried numerous options such as pexpect, uinput (doesn't work that well because of problems with the module). I know that in windows you have the msvcrt module, but I am working with linux... any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: White `\n` to stdin?

Comment: Indeed you could try sending a newline to stdin of the process or you could try closing the stdin of the process entirely if you don't need it.

Comment: yes I have already tried adding /n and also /r/n but that just displayed empty lines in my console and did not activate the following process. But maybe I have set the term at the wrong place..where exactly would you place it in the code I posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an easy and fast way for simulating a key press:

just install xdotool and then use the following code for simulating e.g. the enter key:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["xdotool","key","Return"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pexpect library for *expect* functionnality.

Here's an example of interaction with a an application requiring user to type in his password:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('your command')
child.expect('Enter password:')
child.sendline('your password')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=None)
cmd_show_data =  child.before
cmd_output = cmd_show_data.split('\r\n')
for data in cmd_output:
    print data
```

Comment: yes I have already tried that. but what kind of command am I supposed to spawn? my whole script?